# Get the string which is associated with the highest value increase per year?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm again totally stuck on something with the Windows form project I'm currently developing for improving my C# skills.

I need to get the profession which has the highest salaryincrease per year (return a single string, the profession property of a SalaryInformation object).

Let me show you how the SalaryInformation class looks like:

```
public sealed class SalaryInformation
{
    private string profession;
    private int yearOfEmployment;
    private decimal startSalary;
    private decimal currentSalary;

    public string Profession
    {
        get { return profession; }
        set { profession = value; }
    }

    public int YearOfEmployment
    {
        get { return yearOfEmployment; }
        set { yearOfEmployment = value; }
    }

    public decimal StartSalary
    {
        get { return startSalary; }
        set { startSalary = value; }
    }


    public decimal CurrentSalary
    {
        get { return currentSalary; }
        set { currentSalary = value; }
    }

    public SalaryInformation()
    { }

    public SalaryInformation(string p, int yoe, decimal startS, decimal currentS)
    {
        profession = p;
        yearOfEmployment = yoe;
        startSalary = startS;
        currentSalary = currentS;
    }
```

I already know how to calculate the average salaryincrease per year for a profession:

> salaryIncrease per year = (totalCurrentSalaries - totalStartingSalaries) / totalYears;

Right now my code for the method looks like this:

```
 private string GetProfessionWithHighestSalaryIncrease()
    {
        List<SalaryInformation> allSalaries = new List<SalaryInformation>();
        allSalaries = data.GetSalaryInformation();

        //Here I got stuck. I think that this could be solved in a single linq query.
        //But since I have to make a calculation of EVERY salaryincrease of EVERY
        //profession, I keep getting stuck on how I should solve this.

        //After all, I need the sum of every professions CurrentSalaries, the sum
        //of every professions StartingSalaries and the sum of every professions
        //yearOfEmployment to be able to calculate that professions salaryincrease
        //per year.

        //The profession(string) with the highest salary increase per year, has to  be returned.


    }
```

I'm pretty sure this could be solved in a single combined Linq/lambda expression query. But I'm not used to writing linq and lamdba expressions so I'm struggling with the syntax.

Comment: One thing to be aware of - all your properties could be much shorter if you used automatically implemented properties...

Comment: Are you looking for the highest *average* salary increase, or the highest *one-year* salary increase?

Comment: I'm looking for the highest average salary increase per year. Sorry If I wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use group by to partition the set, then order by the average salary increase and take the first one:

```
string maxSalaryProfession = allSalaries

    // group by profession
    .GroupBy(info => info.Profession)

    // order rows by the average salary increase per profession
    .OrderByDescending(prof => 
        (prof.Sum(info => info.CurrentSalary) - prof.Sum(info => info.StartSalary))
            / prof.Sum(info => info.YearOfEmployment)
     )
     .First().Key;
```

Comment: This looks very interesting and might be the answer. I'm gonna look more into it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

one line:

```
allSalaries.OrderByDescending(s=>(s.CurrentSalary - 
 s.StartSalary)/s.YearOfEmployment).First().Profession
```